# Forward reference tasks not defined before use

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I am using multiple files with `gulp@4` where the main `gulpfile.js` includes all other files within the `./tasks/` directory. We are using the [npm gulp-hub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hub) package to include multiple `gulpfiles` with the `./tasks/` directory. However we are getting the following error message when calling the `tasks`.

> Forward referenced tasks 'clean-minify-js` not defined before use

**How can we include multiple `gulpfiles` within the main `gulpfile.js` so that we can call `tasks`?**

Current `gulpfile.js`:

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    HubRegistry = require('gulp-hub');
    
var genericHub = new HubRegistry('./tasks/scripts.js');
gulp.registry(genericHub);

var watchers = function(done) {
  gulp.watch('src/*.js', gulp.parallel('clean-minify-js'));
  done();
}

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(watchers));
```

Current `./tasks/scripts.js`

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    
gulp.task('clean-scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(dest.js)
             .pipe(clean({read:false, force: true});
});

gulp.task('minify-js', gulp.series('clean-scripts', function() {
   gulp.src(src.js)
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.js));
}));

gulp.task('clean-minify-js', gulp.series('minify-js'));
```

Folder structure:

- `some/path/gulpfile.js`
- `some/path/tasks/scripts.js`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I had to do the following.

- Use the [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir) package to include all files within the `./tasks/` directory.
- convert tasks that were designed for `gulp@3.9.1` into functions for `gulp@4`
- use `gulp.series` to set the functions to run in the particular order we needed

**gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./tasks/');    

var watchers = function(done) {
  gulp.watch('src/*.js', gulp.parallel('clean-minify-js'));
  done();
}

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(watchers));
```

**./tasks/scripts.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

function cleanScripts() {
  return gulp.src(dest.js)
             .pipe(clean({read:false, force: true});
}

function minJs() {
  return gulp.src(src.js)
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.js));
}

gulp.task('clean-minify-js', gulp.series(cleanScripts, minJs));
```